# Using jQuery, how to select all elements where element id ends with some string?

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, how to select all elements where `id` attribute ends with some string?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There an [attribute-ends-with selector (`[attr$=value]`)](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/), like this:

```
$("[id$=something]")
```